# Save Notebooks to GitHub

Tags: git, github, jupyter-notebook, repository, kaggle

After clicking 'Link to GitHub' and go to save a version with copy in Github the save Botton doesn't work. Anybody can tell something about how to fix this issue. I'm trying to save a Kaggle notebooks to Github, and, I can't. Thanks

Comment: How is this question related to python?

Answer (score 1):

Saving (a [Jupyter notebook](https://jupyter.org/) from) [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/) to [Github](https://github.com) **will only work if** you have [first created **at least one** repository in Github](https://github.com/new).

---

<sub>TLDR</sub>

<sub>*Conversely, even if you have "linked" Kaggle to Github, **but have not yet created *any* repository** in the latter, the corresponding **"Save" button** in Kaggle will simply be **grayed-out**:*</sub>

<sub>*As of now (and subject to change on Kaggle's side), **Kaggle itself won't inform you** about **why** the save button is **grayed out**, i.e., the reason being that there is no repository to save to, but rather will only have the "save" button grayed out - without an explanation as to why.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

here are the steps:

1. go to the file and link your GitHub account.
2. then go to save version.
3. click continue you will be given the option to choose your GitHub repo. Select your repo and click save.
4. You can check your repo now for the notebook.

thanks :)